# How to determine which button is pressed on a single tkinter object?

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm creating a noughts and crosses game. I'm quite unfamiliar with classes in Python, however.

The code below is creating a game board. When the user clicks a button, I want to be able to distinguish *that* button from the other buttons, so I know which one was pressed. Is there any way to do this without having to make 9 separate buttons?

I've tried to individually use the event's information to work it out.  However, the `.widget` methods seem to return a different "serial number" each time, while the `event.x` and `event.y` seem to get the *mouse* position and not the *button* position.

I want to be able to use the grid position of the button that the user pressed to hide that button and put a label in its place.

```
#Importing modules
from tkinter import*

#Defining global variables
root = Tk()


class GUI():
    #Class for all widgets
    def __init__(self):
        #Sets up nothing
        pass

    def create_button(self, info, boom, posit):
        #Creates buttons
        self.button = Button(root)
        self.button.config(text=info)
        self.button.bind("<Button-1>",boom)
        self.button.grid(column=posit[0],row=posit[1])

    def create_label(self, info, posit):
        #Creates labels
        self.label = Label(root)
        self.label.config(text=info)
        self.label.grid(column=posit[0],row=posit[1])

    def go_away(self):
        #Makes buttons disappear
        self.button.grid_forget()

    def come_back(self):
        #Makes buttons reappear
        self.button.grid()

    def user_input(self,event):
        print(event.widget)
        #self.go_away()
        #self.create_label("o",self.button.grid)

    def create_board(self):
        for x in range(3):
            for y in range(3):
                self.create_button(" O ",lambda event: self.user_input(event), [x,y])

class Board(GUI):
    def __init__(self):
        self.create_board()
        self.create_label("Hey",[3,0])
        self.board = ["O", "O", "O", "O", "O", "O", "O", "O", "O"]
        self.configure()

    def configure(self):
        row1 = [self.board[0],self.board[1],self.board[2]]
        row2 = [self.board[3],self.board[4],self.board[5]]
        row3 = [self.board[6],self.board[7],self.board[8]]

        colum1 = [self.board[0],self.board[3],self.board[6]]
        colum2 = [self.board[1],self.board[4],self.board[7]]
        colum3 = [self.board[2],self.board[5],self.board[8]]

        self.rows = [row1,row2,row3]
        self.colums = [colum1,colum2,colum3]

nodes = GUI()
board = Board()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: If you use buttons, you must use 9.  An alternative would be a Canvas with horizontal and vertical lines, but then you would have to translate mouse clicks to cells yourself.  (One would probably do this with a chess or checker board instead of 64 buttons.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `command` option of the button rather than a binding, and pass in the coordinates. There are multiple ways to do it -- create a nested function, use lambda, use functools.partial. I prefer using lambda.

First, make sure your function accepts the row and column:

```
def user_input(self, row, column):
    print("row: %s column: %s" % (row, column))
```

Next, set this as the function when you call `create_button`:

```
def create_board(self):
    ...
    cmd = lambda row=y, column=x: self.user_input(row, column)
    self.create_button(" O ", cmd, [x,y])
```

Finally, configure your button to call this function:

```
def create_button(self, info, boom, posit):
    ...
    self.button = Button(root)
    self.button.config(command=boom)
    ...
```

Alternately, you could pass `self.user_input` into `create_button` and move the lambda into `create_button`:

```
...
self.create_button(" 0 ", self.user_input, [x,y])
...

def create_button(self, info, boom, posit):
    ...
    cmd = lambda row=posit[1], column=posit[0]: boom(row, column)
    self.button.config(command=boom)
```

Comment: Perfect thank you! Exactly the solution I was looking for